# Index strategy for queries with dynamic match criteria

Tags: mongodb, indexing, aggregation-framework

I have a collection which is going to hold machine data as well as mobile data, the data is captured on channel and is maintained at single level no embedding of object , the structure is like as follows

```
{
    "Id": ObjectId("544e4b0ae4b039d388a2ae3a"),
    "DeviceTypeId":"DeviceType1",
    "DeviceTypeParentId":"Parent1",
    "DeviceId":"D1",
    "ChannelName": "Login",
    "Timestamp": ISODate("2013-07-23T19:44:09Z"),
    "Country": "India",
    "Region": "Maharashtra",
    "City": "Nasik",
    "Latitude": 13.22,
    "Longitude": 56.32,
    //and more 10 - 15 fields
}
```

Most of the queries are aggregation queries, as used for Analytics dashboard and real-time analysis , the **$match** pipeline is as follows

```
{$match:{"DeviceTypeId":{"$in":["DeviceType1"]},"Timestamp":{"$gte":ISODate("2013-07-23T00:00:00Z"),"$lt":ISODate("2013-08-23T00:00:00Z")}}}
```

or

```
{$match:{"DeviceTypeParentId":{"$in":["Parent1"]},"Timestamp":{"$gte":ISODate("2013-07-23T00:00:00Z"),"$lt":ISODate("2013-08-23T00:00:00Z")}}}
```

and many of my DAL layer **find** queries and **findOne** queries are mostly on criteria **DeviceType** or **DeviceTypeParentId**.

The collection is huge and its growing, I have used compound index to support this queries, indexes are as follows

```
[
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "_id" : 1
                },
                "name" : "_id_",
                "ns" : "DB.channel_data"
        },
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "DeviceType" : 1,
                        "Timestamp" : 1
                },
                "name" : "DeviceType_1_Timestamp_1",
                "ns" : "DB.channel_data"
        },
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "DeviceTypeParentId" : 1,
                        "Timestamp" : 1
                },
                "name" : "DeviceTypeParentId_1_Timestamp_1",
                "ns" : "DB.channel_data"
        }
]
```

Now we are going to add support for match criteria on **DeviceId** and if I follow same strategy as I did for **DeviceType** and **DeviceTypeParentId** is not good,as I fell by my current approach I'm creating many indexes and all most all will be same and huge.
So is their any good way to do indexing . I have read a bit about **Index Intersection** but not sure how will it be helpful.

If any wrong approach is followed by me please point it out as this is my first project and first time I am using MongoDB.

Comment: maybe useful http://askasya.com/post/dynamicattributes

Answer (score 0):

Those indexes all look appropriate for your queries, including the new one you're proposing. Three separate indexes supporting your three kinds of queries are the overall best option in terms of fast queries. You could put indexes on each field and let the planner use index intersection, but it won't be as good as the compound indexes. The indexes are not the same since they support different queries.

I think the real question is, are the (apparently) large memory footprint of the indices actually a problem at this point? Do you have a lot of page faults because of paging indexes and data out of disk?